# Wordpress excerpt not working?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am using wordpress eduma Learn press plugin. The courses page excerpt box is there but text is not displaying. can you please help me? Other pages meta tags is displayed

Comment: Are you talking about excerpt text not displaying while viewing the page or inside the editor?

Comment: excerpt text display while viewing the page not shown

Comment: What is shown instead of excerpt? The whole content?

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your theme

```
add_post_type_support('page', 'excerpt');
```

Answer (score 1):

So is the problem that when viewing the page, the whole content is shown instead of just an excerpt?

If so, try to find the appropriate theme file and if it uses:

```
the_content();
```

replace it with:

```
the_excerpt();
```